# Distinct composition series of $Z_{30}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given two composition series for a group G:
$$\{e \} \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft ... \triangleleft G_k \triangleleft G $$
$$\{e \} \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft ... \triangleleft H_k \triangleleft H $$

If we say they are distinct when $G_i \ncong H_i$ for at least one i. How many distinct composition series does $Z_{30}$ have?

I am a bit confused with this question I initially thought it was linked to the Jordan-Holder theorem and so there would only be 1, but then I realized that this only tells us that series only have the same composition factors up to isomorphism.

I just wanted to check that I am right and this doesn't hold for individual $G_i \cong H_i$ too?

If this is true does anyone have any hints for an easy way to work this out or is it just a case of trying to find all the normal subgroups of $Z_{30}$, and would Sylow theorems possibly help to find these?

Comment: You should have studied cyclic groups before Sylow theorems. The subgroups of a cyclic group of order $n$ are the cyclic subgroups of order $d$, where $d\mid n$ (exactly one for each $d$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find all the normal subgroups of $\Bbb Z_{30}$ without Sylow. The group is abelian, and therefore *all* subgroups are normal. The group is cyclic, so all subgroups are cyclic.

As for how to make different composition series, consider the quotients $G_{i+1}/G_i$. In your case, the three groups that will appear as those quotients will necessarily be $\Bbb Z_2, \Bbb Z_3$ and $\Bbb Z_5$. But you can make them appear in any order.

Comment: Is there 4 distinct composition series in this case then?

Comment: In how many different orders can you put those three quotients?

Comment: Oh 6 that is a better way to work it out! I drew a diagram of all the inclusions between the subgroups but missed two lines!

Answer (score 1):

You already have a good answer.  It might also be useful to know (you can probably do this as an easy exercise now that you understand that order 30 case) that a finite abelian group has only one composition series if and only if it has order the power of a prime.

Answer (score 1):

$Z_{30}={0,1,2,...29}$ (addition $\bmod 30$ here):

$\langle2\rangle= {0,2,4,...28}$
$\langle3\rangle= {0,3,6,...,27}$ and
$\langle5\rangle$, $\langle6\rangle$, $\langle10\rangle$, $\langle15\rangle$ are subgroups of $Z_{30}$ other then ${0}$ and $Z_{30}$.

Therefore, composition series are
${0}⊂\langle15\rangle⊂\langle5\rangle⊂G$
${0}⊂\langle15\rangle⊂\langle3\rangle⊂G$
${0}⊂\langle10\rangle⊂\langle5\rangle⊂G$
${0}⊂\langle10\rangle⊂\langle2\rangle⊂G$
${0}⊂\langle6\rangle⊂\langle3\rangle⊂G$
${0}⊂\langle6\rangle⊂\langle2\rangle⊂G$

for the first series is $\langle5\rangle/\langle15\rangle$
and $|\langle5\rangle/\langle15\rangle|= |\langle5\rangle|/|\langle15\rangle|=6/2=3$ which is prime no.

therefore $\langle5\rangle/\langle15\rangle$ is simple
similarly, we can show that all factor group $G_i/G_{i+1}$ are simple.